# Which is the recommended OS for HP Mini Netbook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I use an old HP MINI Netbook with 2GB RAM 667 MHz , 1.6 GHz Intel Atom N270/N450 processor with built-in Intel graphics. I want to install Ubuntu on my netbook so please suggest me a very light version of Ubuntu OS which has atleast Internet Sharing feature enabled.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Your question is a duplicate but basically lubuntu or xubuntu should do the trick.  I'd personally get ubuntu and install openbox on it. Openbox is very minimal and lightweight. Just need to configure it a bit

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Any of this very lightweight. As you have more than 1gb RAM, any of this is fine. Although Lubuntu is lighter, my personal option is Xubuntu due to personal issues with Lubuntu on an old (very old) Thinkpad laptop. I use Xubuntu on my laptop (Intel Core 2, 4GB RAM) and it works like charm.